# Unable to format label on horizontal axis in google charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, linechart

I am trying to create a graph that shows the fluctuation in bitcoin prices against INR currency. The data is fetched from this link: [Bitcoin API](https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/history/INR/per_hour_monthly_sliding_window.csv)

I have written this code but here are the stuff that I cannot perform.

The label of the horizontal axis of the graph is not getting formatted properly. e.g. Instead of displaying "15-12-31 06:05:09" below the horizontal axis, I wish to display "31 Dec". Besides, I wish to set a title for the graph and corresponding titles for the horizontal and vertical axes as well.

The labels on the vertical axis show numbers like 30K. How can I make it see like "30,000"? The same is needed for the details box that is generated on bringing the mouse over the line graph.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Graph Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/files/jquery.csv-0.71.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="graph">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['line']});
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                function drawChart()
                {
                    $.get("https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/history/INR/per_hour_monthly_sliding_window.csv", function(csvString)
                        {
                             var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
                             var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
                             var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                             view.setColumns([0,3]);

                             var options = {
                                title : "INR/BTC Exchange Rates",
                                hAxis: {
                                    title: "Date",
                                    format: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                                    minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min,
                                    maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max
                                },
                                vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(3), minValue: data.getColumnRange(3).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(3).max},
                                legend: 'none',
                             };

                             var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('graph'));
                             chart.draw(view,options);
                        });
                };

            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```